# Last minor tick not drawn - Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to draw two subplots in the same figure that share the x axis. However, I cannot get it to draw the last minor xtick. I have no idea from where this behaviour comes, but I managed to reproduce it with random data.

The system used is python2.7 and matplotlib v1.2.1

So here goes my minimal error-reproducing example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

xdat = np.linspace(0,6.6,endpoint=True)
ydat1 = np.random.rand(50)*500
ydat2 = np.random.rand(50)*4

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,8), dpi=72)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=[3,1])
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])

ax1.plot(xdat, ydat1)
ax1.set_xlim(0,6.6)
ax1.set_xticks(range(0,8,1))
ax1.minorticks_on()
[label.set_visible(False) for label in ax1.get_xticklabels() ]  # Make tick labels invisible

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1], sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(xdat, ydat2, 'r-')
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=5, steps=[1,2,4,5,10], symmetric=False, prune='upper'))
plt.show()
```

I got the following image:
[image: Example plot where last minor tick is missing]

I have no idea whether I found a bug or if there is an easy way to alleviate this problem (i.e. update matplotlib).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haven't been able to find where the bug comes from yet, but version `1.3.1` has the same behavior.

A work around would be to set the minor ticks manually, by adding a `ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.hstack((ax2.xaxis.get_ticklocs(minor=True), 6.4)), minor=True)`, where `6.4` is the last minor tick.
[image]

Or you can force the `xlim` to be slightly larger than the default and the last tick will come out. `ax2.set_xlim((0,6.6))`. The default is `(0.0, 6.5999999999999996)`.

I guess it can be considered as a bug.